# Casorati-Weierstrass theorem-related proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, solution-verification, singularity

**Theorem.** If $f$ has an essential singularity at $p$, then for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists a sequence $\{z_k\}$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}z_n = p \quad \wedge \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(z_n) = a
\end{equation*}
**Proof I have so far.** I believe that, so far I was able to prove the second condition, i.e.,  $\hspace{.2cm}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(z_n) = a\hspace{.2cm}$ by contradition taking
\begin{equation*}
g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-a}
\end{equation*}
and then considering two cases $\overline{g}(p)\neq 0$ and $\overline{g}(p)=0$. I believe this part is somehow related to the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.

The part where I am struggling is with the first condition, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}z_n = p
\end{equation*}

If someone could help me with this one, I would be really thankfull. (I understand this should be, somehow, related to the definition of convergence of a sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. If the conclusion fails then there exists $r>0$ and $\delta >0$ such that $|f(z)-a| \geq \delta$ for $0<|z-p| <r$. Let $g=\frac  1 {f-a}$ Then $g$ is bounded near $p$ so it has a removable singularity at $p$. Obviously, $g$ is not identically $0$ in $D(p,r)$ so it has a zero of finite order (at most) at $p$. But then $f(z)=a+\frac  1g$ has  a pole at $p$.

Comment: I don't understand how this proves that \begin{equation*} \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}z_n = p \end{equation*} Isn't this a prove for what I have already shown? Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to write down the the negation of what you are asked to prove. That will give you existence of $r$ and $\delta$ as I have stated. @rpd

Comment: I understand that. But aren't you proving (by contradition) that \begin{equation*} \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(z_n) = a \hspace{.1cm} ? \end{equation*} I wanted to prove what I've typed on my first comment, since I've already done this part. If I am missing something I am sorry!

Comment: Suppose what I stated in my first sentence is false. Take $r=\delta=\frac  1 n$. Then we get $z_n$ such that $0<|z_n-p| <\frac  1 n$ and $|f(z_n)-a| <\frac 1 n$. Doesn't that give both $z_n \to p$ and $f(z_n) \to a$? @rpd

Comment: You are right indeed! Thanks for your help!